# Skipping ExtensionData while retrieving all the properties of a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reflection, .net-4.0

I use something like this,

```
var propertyinfo = class_simple.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public));
```

And i get all the public properties of the class_simple along with extensiondata.

Now, how do I actually skip this extensiondata and use other properties by looping through the propertyinfo ?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ExtensionData` is the name of a property in your class:

```
var allButExtensionData = propInfos.Where(p => p.Name != "ExtensionData"
          || typeof(DataMemberAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));
foreach (var prop in allButExtensionData)
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: can't we use some type checking ? Is this the best way to check using the name ? maybe something like typeof(DataMemberAttribute)